# What character set is allowed in Response header values of the following fields?

Tags: http-headers

I am looking for regular expressions for the character sets

```
Expires:
Age:
Cache-Control:
Content-Type:
Last-Modified:
Date:
Content-Length:
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to rfc2616 that details the http specification, section 3: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3

Comment: Though I must say rather than creating the regex yourself, you'd be better off using already existing http header parsers in your favorite language.